# Disable character's replace in search

Tags: search

WP search automatically replaces lithuanian characters to standart (ą => a, č => c, ę = > e). How to disable this auto replacing?

For example: when I type "č" in search field, I also get results with "c" like "Asus A**c**er".

Answer (score 1):

Try to change collation with the following code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'posts_search_orderby', 'alter_query', 20, 2 );
function alter_query( $orderby, $query ) {
    return $orderby . ' COLLATE latin1_general_ci';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you about wp-includes/functions.php?

Comment: No! Never touch the core. I mean functions.php of your theme.

Comment: Hmm, I just added your code at the end of themes/design/functions.php, but nothing happens :(